# jQuery - rough fadeIn transition on hover

Tags: jquery, css, fadein, transition, jquery-hover

I have a div with some contents and then on hover I am trying to FadeIn another span over it while fadding out the container div. 
The problem after the hover the container div goes to opacity 0 then returns to the value I have set. It feels like it blinks. 
I need to be smooth.
Here is my code:

Live JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/alok108/Y7hgs/28/

HTML

```
<div class="campaign-box">
    <a href="#"class="like-box"> 
        <div class="box">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            <span>34234983-80</span>
        </div>    
        <span> </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function () {
    $(".campaign-box span:last").hide();
    $(".campaign-box").hover(function () { 
        $(".box").css("opacity", 0.5);
        $(".campaign-box span:last").fadeIn("fast");           
    }, function () {        
        $(".box").css("opacity", 1); 
        $(".campaign-box span:last").fadeOut("slow");
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.campaign-box {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    border: solid black;
}
.box {
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
.box + span {
    display: block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background: #f1f1f1 url("http://0.tqn.com/d/personalweb/1/G/w/O/FacebookLikeButton1.jpg") no-repeat;
    z-index:5;
}
```

Comment: Those who are having this same issue please check @kalley's answer below and following updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/alok108/Y7hgs/33/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add position: relative; z-index doesn't do anything unless some kind of position other than static is set.

```
.box + span {
    display: block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
    background: #f1f1f1 url("http://0.tqn.com/d/personalweb/1/G/w/O/FacebookLikeButton1.jpg") no-repeat;
    z-index:5;
}
```

Comment: Any link to explanation of why this works? Or just experience?

Comment: z-index needs a position set to take effect.

Comment: Thanks @kalley sorry for being so late. I am accepting your answers now.
Also for others who have this issue here is updated fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/alok108/Y7hgs/33/